# Сравнение указателей на объект класса

Tags: указатели, c++

Мне нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
struct element{
//некие переменные
}
bool isEqualElement(element* firstElement, element* secondElement){
if(firstElement == secondElement){
return true;
}
else {return false;}
```

Верно ли это решение?

Как определить `element::operator==()`?

Comment: да верно, будет истина если оба указателя указывают на одну и туже ячейку памяти

Comment: Эээ... это вы себя должны спросить, верное ли это решение.

По коду, который вы написали, равны будут только физически совпадающие элементы. Правильно ли это для вашей структуры, знаете только вы сами.

Comment: Если Вам нужно именно это, то верное.

@fasfsasf, к сожалению понять, что именно Вам нужно невозможно.

Если Вас интересует равенство 2-х адресов в RAM, то верно.

Comment: Смотря что вы хотите получить. Если хотите проверить, равны ли два экземпляра вашей структуры (имеется в виду равенство полей), то решение неверное. Если же хотите узнать, идентичны ли они (равенство указателей), то верно. Однако второй вариант особого смысла не имеет, а для корректной реализации первого варианта необходимо также определить оператор == для структуры. 

Впрочем, ту же мысль уже помимо меня высказали 4 человека

Answer (score 1):

Если передаётся один и тот же указатель, то вернёт true, иначе false.
`element::operator==()` вызван не будет (используйте ссылки или разыменование указателей)

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от предполагаемой семантики этого кода.
Если судить по названию функции (`isEqualElement`), то решение неверное - производится сравнение *указателей* на элементы, а не самих элементов. Т.е. функция вернет `true` только если входные аргументы указывают на один и тот же объект. Если все же нужно сравнивать именно *содержимое* элементов, то нужно было написать что-то вроде

```
return *firstElement == *secondElement;
```

и определить `element::operator==()`.

Если же требуется убедиться в том, что имеется два указателя на один и тот же объект, то код верный. Только тогда, наверное, функцию логичнее было бы назвать `isSameElement`.

Comment: Ну, для банального сравнения _указателей_ вообще никаких функций не надо создавать.

Comment: @alexolut Согласен. Просто из содержимого вопроса неясно, для чего вообще этот код, вот и рассмотрел оба варианта: то, что собственно реализовано и, что следует из названия функции и соображений общей логики.

Comment: Вопрос давнишний, и автор с тех пор не появлялся судя по информации в профиле. Так что прояснить довольно сомнительно что он хотел :)